# Any way to assign multiple from a function return

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I swear i have seen someone before assign an array split between multiple variables all in one go...

**Looked** structurally something like:

```
['a','b','c'].blank(),a,b,c;
```

where i have put *blank* It was some string or array function. I defiantly remember the commas I just never remembered to try and see if the guys code was legit, I've only gone and lost the post.

The commas just make me think it sounds dumb thinking about it now but I remember looking at it thinking wow he just exploded/threw the code into a bunch of stuff at once..

I would like to know if there is such a method? If not would there be a more eligant way than what I consider to be the normal way?:

```
function abc(){return ['a','b','c'];}

var a,b,c;

a=abc();

b=a[1];

c=a[2];

a=a[0];
```

Comment: The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) separates arbitrary expressions, and are sometimes abused in source code, or are used for minification in optimization compiler tools. You may have seen one of these uses of it.

Comment: You aren't thinking of `map` are you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map Not really what you describe but might fit some usecases.

Answer (score 4):

In ECMAScript 6 you will be able to use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
var [a, b, c] = abc();
```

[Browser support isn't great yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility). You can use [one of many transpilers](https://github.com/esnext/esnext) though to preprocess your code though.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of that.

Comment: plus it didn't look like that

Comment: @8DK For the timeframe, at least, ECMAScript 6 drafts have been published [since July 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony_.286th_Edition.29).